# set checked depending on data-selection value

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, jquery-selectors, accordion

I have a data-selection.

```
<div id="accordion" data-selection="<?php echo $_SESSION['sessionNumber']; ?>">
```

In my accordion, I have an input field

```
<div id="accordion">
  <label class="">
    <h2>title</h2>
    <input type='checkbox'/>
  </label>
  <label class="">
    <h2>title</h2>
    <input type='checkbox'/>
  </label>
</div>
```

So now I have two data-selection 0 and 1 I the checkbox to be checked on the value of the data-selection.

For example, if `data-selection ="0"` the first will be checked if 1 then the second, this needs to be dynamic.

Does anyone know how to do this?

I have done something like this with the active accordion

```
$(function () {
  var $accordion = $("#accordion");
  $accordion.accordion({
    autoHeight: true,
    collapsible: true,
    active: $accordion.data("selection")
  });
}
```

The active state is dynamically set depending on the data-selection value.

I would like the same function for the check.

Answer (score 0):

Give the checkboxes classes or ids you can search for with code like this:

```
//get selection value
var box = $("#accordion").attr('data-selection');
//change checkbox
$('#' + box).attr('checked', 'checked');
```

You could also just put `<?php echo 'checked' ?>` in the proper checkbox when you render it instead of letting JS change it after the fact.

Comment: hmm, so give class 0 , 1, 2, 3 and so on. then if data-selection echo checked ?

Comment: I may come back to this in the morning, its almost midight

Comment: essentially, yes.

Comment: Thanks ill come back to this in a bit and accept answer when i get it working